# Ruta definida, y Laravel muestra un mensaje indicando que no lo está

Tags: laravel

Tengo la siguiente ruta:

```
Route::get('visits/excel/{find?}', 'VisitController@localsVisitsExcel')->name('locals-visits.excel')->middleware('permission:locals-visits.excel');
```

y Larave me muestra el siguiente error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [locals-visits.excel] not defined.
```

Leí que una posible solución sería un Alias, no sé si sea la única y si realmente lo sea, pero no sé sí definí bien el alias en esta ruta en particular.

Definí una Alías:

```
Route::get('visits/excel/{find?}', 'as'=>'locals.visits.excel', 'uses'=>'VisitController@localsVisitsExcel')->middleware('permission:locals-visits.excel');
```

Aún así, me sale el error:

```
Symfony\Component\Routing\Exception\RouteNotFoundException
Route [locals.visits.excel] not defined.
```

Así llamo la ruta:

```
<form method="get" action="{{ route('locals-visits.excel')}}" class="form-inline pb-4">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="search" name="visits" placeholder="Buscar por DNI/Nombres" aria-label="Search" value="{{ app('request')->input('visits') }}">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="date" name="start" value="{{ app('request')->input('start') }}">
    <input type="hidden" class="form-control mr-sm-2" type="date" name="end" value="{{ app('request')->input('end') }}">
    <button class="btn btn-success my-2 my-sm-0" type="submit"><i class="far fa-file-excel"></i> Descargar</a></button>
</form>
```

Para el alías:

```
{{ route('locals.visits.excel')}}
```

Comment: En la definición de la ruta estás poniendo "visits/excel/{find?}". Prueba a ponerla tal y como la llamas, es decir, con un guión: "locals-visits/excel/{find?}"

Comment: No, no funciona tampoco

Comment: Borré el caché de las rutas y al parecer está funcionando, seguiré probando y te aviso.

Comment: Suele pasar. Esto de "cachear" es muy útil pero a veces tiene esos "inconvenientes".

Comment: un posible error es que tengas la ruta duplicada `'visits/excel/{find?}'`, verifica que no no lo este.

Comment: gracias a todos, loresolví con la solución de  cooper, `locals-visits`

Answer (score 0):

Podrías intentar de esta forma, que es colocando la instrucción de name al final.

```
Route::get('visits/excel/{find?}', 'uses'=>'VisitController@localsVisitsExcel')->middleware('permission:locals-visits.excel')->name(locals.visits.excel);
```